# using integerForKey with strings swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am confused about using integer for key in swift. Can someone explain how this works and what value it will return? I would expect it to be able to return an integer associated with a key in a dictionary or array, but don't understand how it will return an integer for a string?

```
import Foundation

// adopted by delegate so it can be notified when settings change
protocol ModelDelegate {
    func settingsChanged()
}

class Model {
    private let regionsKey = "FlagQuizKeyRegions"
    private let guessesKey = "FlagQuizKeyGuesses"

    // reference to QuizViewController to notify it when settings change
    private var delegate: ModelDelegate! = nil

    var numberOfGuesses = 4 // number of guesses to display

    private var enabledRegions = [
        "Africa" : false,
        "Asia" : false,
        "Europe" : false,
        "North_America" : true,
        "Oceania" : false,
        "South_America" : false
    ]

    // variables to maintain quiz data
    let numberOfQuestions = 10
    private var allCountries: [String] = [] // list of all flag names
    private var countriesInEnabledRegions: [String] = []

    // initialize the settings from the app's NSUserDefaults
    init(delegate: ModelDelegate, numberOfQuestions: Int) {
        self.delegate = delegate

        // get the NSUSerDefaults object for the app
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        // get number of guesses
        let tempGuesses = userDefaults.integerForKey(guessesKey)
        if tempGuesses != 0 {
            numberOfGuesses = tempGuesses
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return a Integer for a key which is a String. So let's say:

```
let myKey = "Countries"
let myCountries = ["USA","Brazil","Japan"]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(myCountries.count, forKey: myKey)
let numberOfCountries =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(myKey)   // 3
```